# Breadth First Search for a Slider Puzzle Solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, breadth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

I plan to implement a few other solvers (depth first search, A*, etc), hence why I'm using the abstract base class (which is new to me). I'm using Python 3.6, so you'll see f-string literals. I would appreciate any positive feedback (yay!) or, even more importantly, constructive (yay!) criticism.

```
import abc
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from collections import deque
from math import sqrt
from resource import getrusage, RUSAGE_SELF
from time import time

import numpy as np


class Board:
    def __init__(self, tiles: str, hole: str = '0', sz: int = None):
        board_ = tiles.split(',')
        self._sz = sz or int(sqrt(len(board_)))
        self._sorted_tokens = [str(x) for x in range(self._sz ** 2)]
        self._goal = np.reshape(self._sorted_tokens, (self._sz, -1))
        self._state = np.reshape(board_, (self._sz, -1))
        self._hole = hole

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._state)

    @property
    def goal(self):
        return ','.join(self._sorted_tokens)

    @property
    def string(self):
        return self.stringify(self._state)

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state

    @staticmethod
    def stringify(state):
        return ','.join(state.flatten())

    def hole_pos(self):
        pos = np.where(self._state == self._hole)
        return pos[0][0], pos[1][0]

    def tile(self, pos):
        if pos[0] < 0 or pos[1] < 0:
            raise ValueError('Tile out of bounds!')
        return self._state[pos]

    def act(self, action):
        hole = self.hole_pos()
        lut = {
            'Up': (hole[0] - 1, hole[1]),
            'Down': (hole[0] + 1, hole[1]),
            'Left': (hole[0], hole[1] - 1),
            'Right': (hole[0], hole[1] + 1)
        }
        pos = lut[action]
        board_ = self.swap(pos)
        return board_

    def actions(self):
        """
        find neighboring tiles to hole position
        """
        hole = self.hole_pos()
        actions_ = []
        if hole[0] - 1 >= 0:
            actions_.append('Up')
        if hole[0] + 1 < self._sz:
            actions_.append('Down')
        if hole[1] - 1 >= 0:
            actions_.append('Left')
        if hole[1] + 1 < self._sz:
            actions_.append('Right')
        return actions_

    def swap(self, pos):
        """
        position is tuple (R,C) of neighboring tile to hole
        """
        try:
            hole = self.hole_pos()
            tile = self.tile(pos)
            temp_state = self._state.copy()
            temp_state[pos[0]][pos[1]] = self._hole
            temp_state[hole[0]][hole[1]] = tile
            return Board(self.stringify(temp_state),
                         hole=self._hole,
                         sz=self._sz)
        except ValueError:
            return None


class Node:
    def __init__(self, state=None, action=None, path_cost=None, parent=None):
        self._state = state
        self._action = action
        self._path_cost = path_cost
        self._parent = parent

    def __repr__(self):
        return str({'state': self._state.state,
                    'action': self._action,
                    'path_cost': self._path_cost,
                    'parent': self.parent})

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node._parent

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state

    @property
    def action(self):
        return self._action

    @property
    def path_cost(self):
        return self._path_cost

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    @property
    def depth(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self) - 1  # to account for 0 indexing


class Solver(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, start_board: Board, depth: int = 4):
        self._goal = start_board.goal
        self._start_board = start_board
        self._frontier = deque()
        self._explored = set()
        self._path_cost = 0
        self._nodes_expanded = 0
        self._fringe_sz = 0
        self._max_fringe_sz = 0
        self._search_depth = 0
        self._max_search_depth = 0
        self._running_time = 0
        self._depth_limit = depth

    @property
    def nodes_expanded(self):
        return self._nodes_expanded

    @property
    def fringe_size(self):
        return self._fringe_sz

    @property
    def max_fringe_size(self):
        return self._max_fringe_sz

    @property
    def search_depth(self):
        return self._search_depth

    @property
    def max_search_depth(self):
        return self._max_search_depth

    @property
    def running_time(self):
        return self._running_time

    def update_fringe_size(self):
        self._fringe_sz = len(self._frontier)
        if self._fringe_sz > self._max_fringe_sz:
            self._max_fringe_sz = self._fringe_sz

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def solve(self):
        """
        To be implemented by detailed search strategies
        """
        return


class DFS(Solver):
    def solve(self):
        pass


class AST(Solver):
    def solve(self):
        pass


class IDA(Solver):
    def solve(self):
        pass


class BFS(Solver):
    def solve(self):
        start_time = time()
        root = Node(state=self._start_board,
                    path_cost=self._path_cost)
        self._frontier.append(root)
        if root.state.string == self._goal:
            self._search_depth = root.depth
            self._running_time = time() - start_time
            return root
        while True:
            if len(self._frontier) == 0:
                self._running_time = time() - start_time
                raise ValueError('Goal not found.')
            node = self._frontier.popleft()
            if node.depth > self._depth_limit:
                raise RuntimeError
            if node.state.string == self._goal:
                self.update_fringe_size()
                self._search_depth = node.depth
                self._running_time = time() - start_time
                return node
            self._nodes_expanded += 1
            self._explored.add(node.state.string)
            actions = node.state.actions()
            for action in actions:
                state = node.state.act(action)
                child = Node(state=state,
                             action=action,
                             path_cost=1,
                             parent=node)
                if child.depth > self._max_search_depth:
                    self._max_search_depth = child.depth
                if (child.state.string not in self._explored) and (child not in self._frontier):
                    self._frontier.append(child)
                    self.update_fringe_size()


class Summary:
    def __init__(self, child: Node):
        self._child = child

    def path_cost(self):
        return sum(n.path_cost for n in self._child)

    def actions(self):
        return list(reversed([n.action for n in self._child]))[1:]

    def search_depth(self):
        return self._child.depth


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        parser = ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("solver", help="algorithm (bfs | dfs)")
        parser.add_argument("board", help="board string (0,1,2,3...)")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        board = Board(tiles=args.board)
        print("***STARTING STATE***")
        print(board.state)
        algorithms = {
            'bfs': BFS(board, depth=100),
            # 'dfs': DFS(board, depth=100),
            # 'ast': BFS(board, depth=100),
            # 'ida': BFS(board, depth=100)
        }

        search = algorithms[args.solver]
        res = search.solve()
        print("***SOLUTION STATE***")
        print(res.state)
        print(f"nodes expanded {search.nodes_expanded}")
        summary = Summary(res)
        print(f"path cost {summary.path_cost()}")
        print(f"actions {summary.actions()}")
        print(f"fringe size: {search.fringe_size}")
        print(f"max_fringe_size: {search.max_fringe_size}")
        print(f"search depth {search.search_depth}")
        print(f"max search depth {search.max_search_depth}")
        print(f"running time {search.running_time}")
        print(f"memory usage {getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF)[2]}")
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)
```

Comment: @mayo Please write all critiques in answers, not comments. Comments are for seeking clarification to the question and are subject to deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a high-level overview without diving into the implementation details:

- the `solve()` of your `BFS` class is not readable and quite lengthy - split it into multiple methods and/or add meaningful comments
- overall the program is long - see if you can split it into multiple importable modules
- I would also extract the "reading command-line arguments" and "reporting the results" code blocks into separate functions
- the last set of `print()` calls can be replaced with a single `print()` call and a *multi-line string*
- the `Solver` class may be rewritten using the [`attrs` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs/) making the code more readable avoiding the boilerplate parts
- according to the [Docstring Convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), you should start your docstring with a capital letter and have a dot at the end of sentences. And, if a docstring fits a single line, define it on a single line.
- memory profile your program - it might be that, when you are creating new `Board` instances, the previous instances will be "hanging" and not garbage collected resulting into potential memory leaks